# What's the best way to execute a .jar in java code

Tags: java, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I need develop a "launcher" for a java application. This launcher need be able to:

1. check if main application is up-to-date;
2. if not, download a update;
3. run this application and self terminate.

Something like this:

```
public final class Launcher {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String jarName = args[0];

    if (jarHasUpdate(jarName)
      refreshJar(jarName);

    executeJar(jarName);
  }
}
```

What better way of develop the step 3?

I'm trying 2 distinct ways:

**1- Run another instance of Java**

With the code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("java -jar mainApp.jar");
```

Problem: the launcher still running until mainApp have finished.

**2- Using ClassLoader to load .jar at runtime**

Like this:

```
public final class Launcher {
    @SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "rawtypes" })
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        if (args.length < 2) {
            System.out.println("Invalid number of arguments.");
            System.exit(1);
    }

    Refresh.refreshFile(args[0]);

    // args[0] .jar name
    // args[1] class with main function
    File file = new File(args[0]);

    try (URLClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(new URL[] { file.toURI().toURL() });) {
        Class cls = cl.loadClass(args[1]);
        Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("main", new Class[] { String[].class });
        Object params = new String[] {};
        method.invoke(cls, params);
        }
    }
}
```

Problem: if "mainApp.jar" has dependencies, this isn't loaded.

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way? You've already got a running Java process; why not use it?

Comment: Is there a way to make a .jar update itself?

Comment: To elaborate on what @ElliottFrisch asks: why not simply call into the jar's `main` method directly?  And, no, a jar cannot (safely) update itself; if you end up needing to load a class at any point after the original jar has been overwritten, you will end up with a `NoClassDefFoundError` because the file descriptor will no longer match the original.

Comment: You might look at install4j.

Comment: @MikeStrobel, in this case the question may be: how can I dynamically load mainApp.jar and execute this main method? I'm trying it with ClassLoader, but without success.